# Share folder through C#

Tags: c#

How to share folder through C#.
[image]

If I check checkbox (see picture) than I have what I need.
But I want do this with C#, by just having folder path in local.

Comment: You need to add reference to `System.Management` dll and code accordingly.

Comment: Have you ever check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425864.aspx article and try to set `WHSSharePermissions` enum? Or maybe there is a way to do it in WMI..

Comment: As a whole we dont code stuff like this for you - in your many googlings did you not find any code to try?

Comment: I have not found simple solution. Somethink like "create folder with IsShared = true;" I don't expect from you to code for me. I would just like to know simple solution, does not have to be nice, since I need this for Integration test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code share folder

```
private static void QshareFolder(string FolderPath, string ShareName, string Description)
{
try{
    // Create a ManagementClass object

    ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");

    // Create ManagementBaseObjects for in and out parameters

    ManagementBaseObject inParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

    ManagementBaseObject outParams;

    // Set the input parameters

    inParams["Description"] = Description;

    inParams["Name"] = ShareName;

    inParams["Path"] = FolderPath;

    inParams["Type"] = 0x0; // Disk Drive

    //Another Type:

    // DISK_DRIVE = 0x0

    // PRINT_QUEUE = 0x1

    // DEVICE = 0x2

    // IPC = 0x3

    // DISK_DRIVE_ADMIN = 0x80000000

    // PRINT_QUEUE_ADMIN = 0x80000001

    // DEVICE_ADMIN = 0x80000002

    // IPC_ADMIN = 0x8000003

    //inParams["MaximumAllowed"] = int maxConnectionsNum;

    // Invoke the method on the ManagementClass object

    outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);

    // Check to see if the method invocation was successful

    if ((uint) (outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)

    {

        throw new Exception("Unable to share directory.");

    }

}catch (Exception ex)
{
//MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error!");
}
}
```

More detail here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18624/How-to-Share-Windows-Folders-Using-C

Comment: very nice. Thanks.